# Memory access violation in objects vector

Tags: c++, object, memory, vector

I am getting the following error while accessing the "put" method of the HashMap class. I am using VS2008 to compile the following code.

**Unhandled exception at 0x00eece26 in abc.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0xfeeefefe.**

In the main function, I am creating a vector of HashMap objects. When I try to call "put" method of the "HashMap" class, it gives the above mentioned error. 
It works fine with single object but with vector of objects it crashes. Any help?
Thanks a lot.

I am using the following class definitions

```
class HashMap 
{
private:
      int TABLE_SIZE;
      LinkedHashEntry **table;

public: 
      HashMap(void){}

      HashMap(int tableSize) 
      {
            TABLE_SIZE = tableSize;
            table = new LinkedHashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                  table[i] = nullptr;
      }


      double get(int key) 
      {
            int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);       
            if (table[hash] == nullptr)
                  return -1;
            else 
            {
                  LinkedHashEntry *entry = table[hash];    
                  while (entry != nullptr && entry->getKey() != key)                     
                        entry = entry->getNext();

                  if (entry == nullptr)
                        return -1;
                  else                    
                        return entry->getValue();
            }
      }


      void put(int key, double value) 
      {
            int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
            if (table[hash] == nullptr)
                  table[hash] = new LinkedHashEntry(key, value);
            else 
            {
                  LinkedHashEntry *entry = table[hash];   
                  while (entry->getNext() != nullptr)
                        entry = entry->getNext();

                  if (entry->getKey() == key)
                        entry->setValue(value);
                  else
                        entry->setNext(new LinkedHashEntry(key, value));
            }
      }     

  // ...
};
```

The definition of LinkedHashEntry is as follows.

```
class LinkedHashEntry 
{
private:
  int key;
  double value;
  LinkedHashEntry *next;

public:
  LinkedHashEntry(int key, double value) {
        this->key   = key;
        this->value = value;
        this->next  = nullptr;
  }

  int getKey() {
        return key;
  }

  double getValue() {
        return value;
  }

  void setValue(double value) {
        this->value = value;
  }

  LinkedHashEntry *getNext() {
        return next;
  }

  void setNext(LinkedHashEntry *next) {
        this->next = next;
  }
};
```

Here is the main method, where I am creating a vector array.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // ...

    // works fine here
    HashMap objTest(17);
    objTest.put(1,1.1);

    std::vector<HashMap> objHashTable(10, HashMap(17));          
    // crashes here 
    objHashTable[0].put(1, 1.1);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I compiled and ran this on both Mingw4.8/QtCreator and VS2012. No access violation error.

Comment: Are you sure that `unprunedObjCount > 0`?

Comment: @Borgleader I am using VS2008. Can it be a reason?

Comment: @JaredC Yes unprunedObjCount > 0, I also tried by changing it with constant.

Comment: @shaikh If [this code](http://ideone.com/gzX2Oh) does error, then *it could be*. If it does not error, you're doing something wrong elsewhere. This version is your version where I replaced NULL with nullptr (I didn't have the include), replaced some variables with constants, and erased the `...`. You might have to re-change nullptr back to NULL as it is a C++11 feature.

Comment: `LinkedHashEntry **table` - instant turn-off. Is this C++? Why?

Comment: Does `HashMap` have a copy constructor that isn't being shown?

Comment: @sehe Infact I am using this code from some other place. I am not good at C++. What could be other option than using "LinkedHashEntry **table".

Comment: @JaredC No, It has only a default constructor and a constructor shown in above code.

Comment: @shaikh just use `std::list`, `std::slist` or `std::forward_list`

Comment: Strike that, use `std::unordered_map` to implement the HashMap in the first place?!

Comment: Are you following the rule of the three? (i.e. provide copy constructor, assignment and destructor?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas although I am not using copy constructor, but in LinkedHashEntry class I am using "LinkedHashEntry *next;". It seems to me that it is a cause of problem. But I am not sure.

Comment: If you have a destructor but don't follow the Rule of Three, you will crash with that code. Is the "..." a destructor? Plus, if you don't provide a copy constructor, all your maps will be the same.

Comment: You **are** using the copy constructor, just not explicitly in the code. The implementation of `std::vector` will copy the elements when it needs to grow the underlying buffer, if you don't have a copy constructor, the compiler will generate one for you that copies the pointers, the old object will then be destroyed, releasing the memory (assuming you do release the memory in the destructor) and the object in the vector will have a dangling pointer that could very well cause a segmentation fault...ç

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code appears to be a living memory leak and maintenance nightmare to begin with.

I couldn't observe it crashing from the code posted, but both

```
    table = new LinkedHashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
```

and

```
    table[hash] = new LinkedHashEntry(key, value);
```

are never being freed.

### I suggest rewriting `main` using less error-ridden/prone classes: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::unordered_map<int, double> HashMap;

static const int hashTableSize = 17;

int main()
{
    // works fine here
    HashMap objTest(hashTableSize);
    objTest[1] = 1.1; // or objTest.insert({ 1, 1.1 });

    std::vector<HashMap> objHashTable(10, HashMap(hashTableSize));

    // works fine here too
    objHashTable[0].insert({ 1, 1.1 });

    // ZEN achieved; no memory leaks
}
```

See it **[live  on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9e20b9cc0815e9d54ab3c832435eaf3b-bff069f172c3f5c3bc4a5e28d7ac9796)**

Comment: How can I include "unordered_map" in VS2008? Do I need to install boost?

Comment: You might find it as std::tr1::unordered_map or you could just use std::map (dropping the constructor argument)

Comment: In VS2008, 'objHashTable[0].insert({ 1, 1.1 });' is not working. However '(objHashTable[0])[1] = 1.1;' is working. I don't know why.